# Convert Angle C#

Tags: c#, math, geometry, angle

I want to the convert an spinning angle on an Circle converted to another system. The Source System is seen on the left and the target on the right. With which operation can I convert these angles?

[image]

Comment: Probably because you haven't shown any attempt to solve the issue yourself. On StackOverflow it is very important to show that you are asking for help because you are stuck implementing or researching an issue, rather than just asking someone to complete the entire task for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double rightAngle = 90 - leftAngle;
if (rightAngle < 0)
  rightAngle += 360;
```

Comment: This does not work since the left circle is counterclockwise and the right ist clockwise.

Comment: It works, notice `-` sign. Simple check 0 => 90, 90 => 0, 180 => 270, 270 => 180.